# Draw lattice of all subuniverses or congruences

Tags: universal-algebra, congruence-relations

I am solving this exercise:

> Draw lattices of all subuniverses and of all congruences of $(\mathbb{N}, \star)$, where $x \star y$ is defined as $\max(x, y) + 1$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers $1,2,3,\ldots$

I know the definitions, but I cannot proceed to how to determine and draw ALL the subuniverses and congruences. For the subuniverses, I would start perhaps with finding all subalgebras? To be honest, I started with listing some random possible subalgebras, but this doesn´t seem to be the perfect method.

I really don't know how to apply the definitions on this and would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: already tried to solve a part of this question (see my answer) about subalgebras. Main problem is still how to draw them.

Comment: All subuniverses have a rather simple form, do you see what it is? (HINT: how many subuniverses are there containing $3$?) Put another way, can you show that every subalgebra is generated by a single element?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think is is always in a form m, m+1, m+2, ....to the infinity. So each such subalgebra is generated by m and m can be any natural numbers. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. Now writing "$[k]$" for the subalgebra generated by a number $k$, how do $[m]$ and $[n]$ compare for $m>n$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think I know where you are getting. I will try to make this a separate answer maybe. :) But I still struggle mainly with the congruences tbh.

Comment: I don't care about the points, but I'm surprised you didn't end up awarding the bounty. If there's still anything about my answer that's not clear to you, just let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer correctly describes the subalgebras (except that you've forgotten about the empty subalgebra). You ask "how would you draw the lattice"? Well, writing $A_n$ for the subalgebra $\{x\in \mathbb{N}\mid x\geq n\}$, we have $A_n\subseteq A_m$ if and only if $m\leq n$. So the lattice is just an infinite descending chain, with the empty subalgebra at the bottom:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A_1\\ @AAA \\ 
A_2\\ @AAA \\
A_3\\ @AAA \\
\vdots\\
\varnothing
\end{CD}
$$

Ok, what about the congruences? Suppose $\approx$ is a congruence on $(\mathbb{N},\star)$. If $n\approx m$ with $n<m$, what other instances of $\approx$ are forced on us? Well, we must have $n\star k\approx m\star k$ for all $k$. Now there are three cases:

*Case 1:* $k< n$. Then $n\star k = n+1$ and $m\star k = m+1$, so $n+1\approx m+1$.

*Case 2:* $n\leq k\leq m$. Then $n\star k = k+1$ and $m\star k = m+1$. So $k+1\approx m+1$. Note that this is stronger than what we learned from Case 1, since we get $n+1\approx m+1$ in the special case $k= n$.

*Case 3:* $m< k$. Then $n\star k = k+1$ and $m\star k = k+1$. This case tells us nothing, since $k+1\approx k+1$ is always satisfied.

Ok, but from Case 2, we see that all the elements in the interval $[n+1,m+1]$ are congruent to $m+1$. In particular, $m\approx m+1$, and since $n\approx m$, we have $n\approx m+1$ as well. Since $m\approx m+1$, by Case 1 $m+1\approx m+2$, $m+2\approx m+3$, etc. So all the elements in the interval $[n,\infty)$ are congruent.

This gives us a clear picture of the possible congruences: First, there is the discrete congruence $=$. If $\approx$ is not discrete, then there is a least $n$ such that $n\approx m$ with $n<m$. By the analysis above, $[n,\infty)$ is one congruence class, and $\{k\}$ is a congruence class for all $k<n$, by how we defined $n$. Let's call this congruence $\approx_n$.

To be careful, let's check that $\approx_n$ is actually a congruence. By symmetry of $\star$, it suffices to show that if $a\approx_n b$, then $a\star c \approx_n b\star c$. If $a < n$, then $a = b$, so $a\star c = b\star c$. If $a \geq n$, then $b\geq n$, so $a\star c\geq a+1 \geq n$ and $b\star c\geq b+1\geq n$, and thus $a\star c \approx_n b\star c$.

The discrete congruence $=$ is least, and we have ${\approx_n} \subseteq {\approx_m}$ if and only  if $m \leq n$. So again we get an infinite descending chain, with the discrete congruence at the bottom:

$$
\begin{CD}
\approx_1\\ @AAA \\ 
\approx_2\\ @AAA \\
\approx_3\\ @AAA \\
\vdots\\
=
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great! I have just one question: why must we have $n\star k\approx m\star k$ for all $k$? I am usually using "$n_1 \approx n_2 \land m_1 \approx m_2 \Rightarrow n_1 * m_1 \approx n_2 * m_2$". Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: Also, what do you mean be the "discrete congruence"?

Comment: Just nitpicking about your typesetting: in the last paragraph, where you wrote $\approx_n \subseteq \approx_m$, perhaps ${\approx_n} \subseteq {\approx_m}$, typeset as  `${\approx_n} \subseteq {\approx_m}$` will look better. I think this is because both $\approx$ and $\subseteq$ are relational symbols they have spacing around in a certain way which is somehow destroyed by the fact they are chained together; the curly braces make, in this case, the $\approx$ symbols be seen as just another (common) symbol, and so the spacing around $\subseteq$ is correct.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova From the context, it seems that the discrete congruence $\theta$ is such that $$\theta=\{(n,n):n\in\mathbb N\}.$$ I never came up with this name, but it is clearly defined: "...the discrete congruence $=$."

Comment: @TerezaTizkova About your first question, notice that if you make $n_2=m_2=k$ you obtain the requirement made by Alex. For the converse, if $n_1\approx n_2$ and $m_1\approx m_2$ then using Alex's requirement, $$n_1*m_1\approx n_2* m_1\approx n_2*m_2,$$ where the last equivalence follows again by Alex's requirement and commutativity.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks, I've fixed the spacing.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova If $n\approx m$, we also have $k\approx k$ (since every congruence is reflexive), so $n\star k\approx m\star k$. As amrsa explains, the two statements are equivalent if $\star$ is commutative. In general, for a binary operation $\star$, we have that $\approx$ is a congruence if and only if it is an equivalence relation and (a) $x\approx y$ implies $x\star z\approx y\star z$ and (b) $x \approx y$ implies $z\star x\approx z\star y$. For higher arity operations, it suffices to be able to swap out any one input for a congruent one while keeping the other inputs constant.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry, I didnt want to make you feel offended or something. The "nonsence" was referring to my own thoughts on this, since I am still new to this area. I am trying to close or delete the other question, hope that you are okay with that. Apologize. :)

Answer (score 2):

**(Partial) answer to how would I find the subalgebras:**

Suppose $\mathfrak{A}$ is a subalgebra of $(\mathbb{N}, \ast)$. What can I say about it?

- Considering the standard ordering on $\mathbb{N}$, it always
  contains a smallest element
- Because $\mathfrak{A}$ is nonempty, for any element, I can always find finite number of smaller elements
- The operation can be interpreted such that for any $a \in \mathfrak{A}, a \ast a = a + 1$ - hence $a + 1$ is still contained in
  $\mathfrak{A}$
- If I "iterate" the above, $(a + 1) \ast (a + 1) = (a + 1) + 1$ - hence the above-said property is still kept

These properties can be formalized: $a \in \mathfrak{A} \implies (\forall b \geq a) \: b \in \mathfrak{A}$. Each set of the form $\{a, a+1, ... \mid a \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is always a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{A}$, since the operation $\ast$ cannot "return" anything smaller than the smallest element + 1.

**Conculsion:** All the subalgebras $(\mathbb{N}, \ast )$ are in this form: $\{a, a+1, ... \mid a \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Could you check if my thought process is correct and how would you draw the lattice of these subalgebras? (Since it goes to infinity, I am not sure how to visualize).