# What is a discrete congruence?

Tags: equivalence-relations, universal-algebra, congruence-relations

I know a congruence (or congruence relation) is an equivalence relation on an algebraic structure, compatible with the operation on the structure. I am also familiar with equivalent definitions.

However, I am not able to find anything about what is a "discrete congruence". I came accross this term somewhere on stackexchange once and wonder how is it defined.

Can you help me explain what a discrete congruence is? My guess is that it is equivalence relation where every equivalence class has only one element? But it may be nonsense.

Comment: I've never even heard of a "discrete congruence" before, but searching for "discrete congruence" (with the double quotes) in the site's black search bar, there was one result, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4297204/602049) from $2$ days ago. About two-thirds of the way down, there's a paragraph starting with "This gives us a clear picture of the possible congruences: First, there is the discrete congruence $=$. ...". I hope this helps.

Comment: @John Omilean Yes, that answer you mentioned is exactly the reason I am asking it in this separate question. I either never heard about it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The discrete congruence" on a structure $X$ (and also "the discrete equivalence relation" on a set $X$) refers to the equality relation $=$ on $X$: $$\{(a,a)\mid a\in X\}.$$
This is the minimal congruence / equivalence relation on $X$. Its equivalence classes are singletons.

In contrast, the maximal congruence / equivalence relation on $X$ is called "the trivial congruence" (or "the trivial equivalence relation"): $$\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in X\}.$$ It has a single equivalence class, $X$.

I believe the terminology comes from an analogy with the maximal and minimal topologies on a set: the discrete topology (in which singletons are open) and the trivial topology (in which the only non-empty open set is $X$). The terminology, while not universal, is at least somewhat common, as a google search reveals:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+discrete+equivalence+relation%22

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+discrete+congruence%22